# How do I correctly specify dtype value types for an input .txt file with multiple data types?

Tags: python, list, parsing, dtype

I am trying to open a .txt file using np.genfromtxt that I will then put into an empty list that I created: PatDat[]. I would love some input on what I am doing wrong with how I entered the dtype information when I try to open the file. I have tried setting dtype=None, I tried explicitly labeling each column of data and have also tried to set dtype equal to another variable defined above input_file and calling it below. The file I am trying to use is a .txt file with multiple rows and columns and includes string, float, and integer data types. When I run the file, I get the error:
TypeError: genfromtxt() got multiple values for argument 'dtype'.

```
input_file = np.genfromtxt('F:\\Admin\Programming_Files\\BIOE Files\\Python\\input_file.txt',\ 'r', dtype = [('Name', '<U6'), ('Height', '<f8'), ('Weight', '<f8'), ('Sex', '<i4'),\ ('Age', '<i4'), ('ActLev', '<i4'), ('SBP', '<i4'), ('DBP', '<i4')],\ names= "Name,Height, Weight, Sex, Age, ActLev, SBP, DBP", encoding =None)
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please **do  not post images of code, or links to code, or for that matter, links to images of code**. Please post all code as formatted text in the question itself. Please *always* provide a [mcve]. If you are working with data, post a small example

Comment: Noted! Thank you for letting me know. I will make sure that is what I do from now on with my questions.

Comment: You should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70164554/edit) to adhere to the standards or else this question will probably get closed. Note, you should check out [ask] and the [help]

Comment: But note, the problem is that you are passing a second positional argument, `'r'`, but the second positional argument **is `dtype`**, but then you also pass a named argument `dtype=...`). Hence the error. I'm not sure what that `'r'` was supposed to be (is it a typo because you wrote it reflexively after the file path like with `open`?), but I think you probably just need to remove it altogether and the above should work

Comment: I think I removed the picture, is it still showing up?